# How to convert custom data type into string

Tags: pascal, custom-data-type

I have this as my custom data type:

```
type
    Status = (Playing, Pausing, Stopping, Display, Selected);
```

And I wanted to output some of these using `DrawText` from SwinGame library:

```
arrayOfStatus[0] := Playing;
DrawText(arrayOfStatus[0], 'arial.ttf', 14, 55, 55);
```

It said `"Got "Status", expected "AnsiString"` which was kinda understandable cuz it only accept strings, and `arrayOfStatus` had a `Status` type. So how do I convert that into a string? I only know `IntToStr` as a converter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, status neither are Strings nor numerical constants. You'll need return values explicitely for each status. An example could be a function returning strings for each status:

```
Function Str_Status(St: Status): String;
Begin
Result:= '';
Case St Of
Playing: Result:= 'Playing';
Pausing: Result:= 'Pausing';
Stopping: Result:= 'Stopping';
// ... and so on
End; //Of case
End; //Of function

//Usage example:

Var State: String;
Begin
State:= Str_Status(arrayOfStatus[0]);
If State <> '' Then
  DrawText(State, 'arial.ttf', 14, 55, 55);
End;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked out for me, but can you please explain why you had `Result:="";` in there? Is that necessary?

Comment: Result:= ''; is a default value if later you add more status and you've  forgot to specify a value to return. It's merely for security. It's a good practice to secure your code against yourself. If you specify "Str_Status(Display)" in the example Str_Status will return an empty text. Please note that's optional: If you think you'll not make a mistake in the future, using a defaut result is not neccesary.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your custom data type as an `enumeration`. An `enumeration` is an ordinal type with default values starting from 0 (zero) and increasing with 1 for each declared member. (See note below regarding variations of this scheme).

```
type
  Status = (Playing, Pausing, Stopping, Display, Selected);
```

As it is an ordinal type, it can be used to index an array, and thus you can declare a `const` array to hold the string representation of each `Status`:

```
const
  StatusStr:array[Status] of string =
    ('Playing', 'Pausing', 'Stopping', 'Display', 'Selected');
```

Here's a simple test to print them out in a `TMemo`

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: status;
begin
  for i := Low(Status) to High(Status) do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(StatusStr[i]);
end;
```

Or assigning the caption of a label

```
StatusLabel.Caption := StatusStr[Playing];
```

---

**Note!** The ordinality of the members of an enumeration can be changed by declaring specific values to the members, f.ex.:

```
type
  TMyEnum = (First = 1, Second, Third = 10);
```

Here, the ordinal values of the members are 1, 2, 10.

As this is beyond the scope of your question, look in the documentation for rules and limitations regarding these enumerations.